# how to get several numbers within same classes

Tags: javascript, html, class, parseint, getelementsbyclassname

I am new to Javascript.
I have a question. here is a HTML code:

```
<div class="priceBox cargoPriceBox">
                <div class="title">Classe affaires</div>
                <div class="price">Tarif actuel du billet : <b>5 175 $</b></div>
                <div class="demand">Demande : 192 Pax</div>
                <div class="paxLeft" title="J+1">
                                        Demande restante : <span class="greenBonus" title="left">20 Pax</span>
                                    </div>
                                <div class="auditCa">Chiffre d'affaires : <b>993 600 $</b></div>
                            </div>
            <div class="priceBox cargoPriceBox">
                <div class="title">Première classe</div>
                <div class="price">Tarif actuel du billet : <b>10 224 $</b></div>
                <div class="demand">Demande : 12 Pax</div>
                <div class="paxLeft" title="J+1">
                                        Demande restante : <span class="greenBonus" title="left">27 Pax</span>`enter code here`
```

I want to get all numbers withing classe="greenBonus" so 20 and 27.
I use the following code but it doesn't work

```
function getPAX(index) {
  return parseInt(
   document.getElementsByClassName("greenBonus").children[index].innerHTM);

}
```

Please help me,
thankx

Answer (score 0):

You can fetch all of the elements and then iterate over them and add the number using parseInt()

```js
const res = document.getElementsByClassName("greenBonus");
let x = '';
for (var i=0;i<res.length;i++) {
    x += ' ' + parseInt(res[i].innerHTML);
}
console.log(x)
```

```html
<div class="priceBox cargoPriceBox">
                <div class="title">Classe affaires</div>
                <div class="price">Tarif actuel du billet : <b>5 175 $</b></div>
                <div class="demand">Demande : 192 Pax</div>
                <div class="paxLeft" title="J+1">
                                        Demande restante : <span class="greenBonus" title="left">20 Pax</span>
                                    </div>
                                <div class="auditCa">Chiffre d'affaires : <b>993 600 $</b></div>
                            </div>
            <div class="priceBox cargoPriceBox">
                <div class="title">Première classe</div>
                <div class="price">Tarif actuel du billet : <b>10 224 $</b></div>
                <div class="demand">Demande : 12 Pax</div>
                <div class="paxLeft" title="J+1">
                                        Demande restante : <span class="greenBonus" title="left">27 Pax</span>`enter code here`
```

Answer (score 0):

you can target the elements with `class="greenBonus"` like this, it will return an array containing the elements

```js
const greenBonus = document.getElementsByClassName("greenBonus");
```

you can use the traditional `for loop` to do this but i will use the [map](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_map.asp) method here

you can use the `map` method on the array and get the innerText of the elements and use the `parseInt` method to convert them to numbers

```js
const texts = [...greenBonus].map((i) => parseInt( i));
```

final code :

```html
<div class="priceBox cargoPriceBox">
                <div class="title">Classe affaires</div>
                <div class="price">Tarif actuel du billet : <b>5 175 $</b></div>
                <div class="demand">Demande : 192 Pax</div>
                <div class="paxLeft" title="J+1">
                                        Demande restante : <span class="greenBonus" title="left">20 Pax</span>
                                    </div>
                                <div class="auditCa">Chiffre d'affaires : <b>993 600 $</b></div>
                            </div>
            <div class="priceBox cargoPriceBox">
                <div class="title">Première classe</div>
                <div class="price">Tarif actuel du billet : <b>10 224 $</b></div>
                <div class="demand">Demande : 12 Pax</div>
                <div class="paxLeft" title="J+1">
                                        Demande restante : <span class="greenBonus" title="left">27 Pax</span>
```

```js
function getPax(){
const greenBonus = document.getElementsByClassName("greenBonus");
const texts = [...greenBonus].map((i) => parseInt( i.innerText));
}
```

the output of this will be `27, 20`

i hope this helps :D

Comment: @ollium is this what you are trying to get? lemme know if you have any doubts

Comment: Dont use content of dom to calculate logic or prices.

Comment: @Grumpy hmm why so? but it is what he wanted

Comment: @coder: actually i am trying to edit a chrome app. The original app collects these numbers on another web page and I want to edit it so it collects the data from this page (html code above)

Comment: @ollium Yeah isnt that what my code does?